# Why does Modelsim say that VHDL shared variables must be protected?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, variable

So I created a shared variable in a purely non-synthesizeable code.

When compiling ModelSim generates a warning:

> (vcom-1236) Shared variables must be of a protected type.

Why is it a warning and not an error if the shared variable *must* be "protected"?
What does protected even mean in this case i.e protected from what?

The shared variable is just a `std_logic`.

Comment: Starting in IEEE Std 1076-2002 shared variables are of protected types (accessed by methods instead of assigned or evaluated directly). The default standard revision used by recent Modelsim versions is -2002.

Comment: What is the northern behind this change for shared variables? Certainly it overcomes some drawbacks that they have right?

Comment: [Protected Shared Variables in VHDL: IEEE Std 1076a](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.8679&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (The first thing that comes up googling using *VHDL mutual exclusion protected type*).

Comment: There were issues with vendor implementations of shared variables before 2002. The the newer standard revisions enforce protected types, so shared variables have a well defined behavior: in your designs and in different simulators. That does not mean that all vendors, who claim to support VHDL-2008, have a correct protected type implementation ... !! I have a testcase which shows, that their simulator has the same faulty shared variable implementation like the predecessor product (which supported only VHDL-93) developed by the same company :).

Comment: If you use GHDL use `-frelaxed-rules` switch to relax this issue to warning.

Answer (score 2):

Non-protected shared variables are fine if you know what you are doing, and I would personally prefer if Modelsim did not produce the warning. (It is not present if you compile for VHDL-93.)

In your case you could replace your shared `std_logic` variable with a small protected type with an internal variable and `set` and `get` procedures. This would get rid of the warning, but provide zero extra protection.

Not to say that protected types are not useful in some situations.